# Hybrid Mobile Application - Compare with the different aspects

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, hybrid-mobile-app

Hybrid Mobile Application development tools for best application to deliver to clients:

1. Which product/platform is truly cross-platform?
2. Which product/platform provides most native capability?
3. What is product/platform provides best ALM(Application Lifecycle Management)?
4. What product/platform has most compatibility to EMM/MDM’s (Enterprise Mobile Management/Mobile Device Management)?
5. What product/platform provides best ROI(Return On Investment)?